# What are the different uses of "heaven" in scripture?

Tags: heaven, eschatology

In English, heaven is used through both testaments, but is often referencing different locations. What are the specific uses for this word?

Comment: I personally don't see this as too broad. Just like "hell" there are only a few words in the Scripture translated "heaven" or "heavens". However, this might be better on the [Biblical Hermeneutics site](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com). Examining translations and looking at exact word meanings is what they do there.

Answer (score 3):

5 Biblical/Theological Understandings of Heaven

1. The Sky: "God called the expanse **heaven** And there was evening and there was morning, a second day" (Genesis 1:8).
2. The Abode of God: God's existence outside of space and time.
3. The intermediate state for the righteous between death and bodily resurrection: "Today you shall be with me in **paradise**" (Luke 23:43). See, [What is the difference between Heaven/Paradise/Sheol?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/508/heaven-paradise-sheol-hell-hades-the-lake-of-fire)
4. The kingdom or reign of God here on earth: "From that time on Jesus began to preach, “Repent, for the kingdom of heaven has come near.” (Matthew 4:17).
5. The Eschatological Heaven: This is the final heaven. "Then I saw “a new heaven and a new earth,” for the first heaven and the first earth had passed away, and there was no longer any sea.  I saw the Holy City, the new Jerusalem, coming down out of heaven from God, prepared as a bride beautifully dressed for her husband" (Revelation 21:1-2) (also see 2 Peter 3:13).

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are three types of heavens mentioned in Bible though they have in OT used the same word [You can see here](http://www.scripture4all.org/OnlineInterlinear/OTpdf/gen1.pdf), The links also state the same, [1](http://www.ucg.org/bible-faq/what-does-bible-mean-third-heaven), [2](http://www.letusreason.org/Biblexp130.htm)

1. the Sky or Terrestrial Heavens

> God made the expanse, and separated the waters which were below the expanse from the waters which were above the expanse; and it was so. God called the expanse heaven. And there was evening and there was morning, a second day. Genesis 1:7-8

2. the Space or Telestial Heavens

   > Then God said, “Let there be lights in the expanse of the heavens to separate the day from the night, and let them be for signs and for seasons and for days and years; and let them be for lights in the expanse of the heavens to give light on the earth”; and it was so. God made the two great lights, the greater light to govern the day, and the lesser light to govern the night; He made the stars also. God placed them in the expanse of the heavens to give light on the earth, and to govern the day and the night, and to separate the light from the darkness; and God saw that it was good. here was evening and there was morning, a fourth day.  Genesis 1:14-19
3. Where God lives: Celestial Heavens

   > hear in heaven Your dwelling place, ....   1 Kings 8:43

or

> Our Father who is in heaven,
>   Hallowed be Your name. Mathhew 6:9